# Postgres: modify each array element

Tags: arrays, postgresql, liquibase

I have a postgres column double[]: {100, 101, 102}.

I want to divide each element by 10, so the result should be {10.0, 10.1, 10.2}.

I've only found solutions with for-statements, but how to realize this with a simple query? (I need to update through liquibase)

The alternative is to write a Java-migration, but I would prefer a simple query...

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

A second problem that arose is:

When doing this through a Liquibase java-migration script, you get a `liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection` (through `liquibase.change.custom.CustomTaskChange`), which of course does not support postgres-arrays =/.

How to handle arrays this way? (I use liquibase-core 3.5.5)

Comment: This would be so easy with a properly normalized data model

Comment: I know right :) The downside on the other side would be a lot of extra tables, references, etc... since we got about 8 properties as array, each with about 3000 values

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to unnest, divide, then aggregate back.

```
update the_table
  set the_array = array(select t.val / 10 
                        from unnest(the_table.the_array) as t(val));
```

If you need to preserve the original order in the array use `with ordinality`

```
update the_table
  set the_array = array(select t.val / 10 
                        from unnest(the_table.the_array) with ordinality as t(val,idx) 
                        order by t.idx);
```

---

To run this in Liquibase you need to use a `<sql>` change

Online example: https://rextester.com/IJGA96691

Comment: You're my hero! Thx!